# In Sharepoint 2013, how do I "check in" files through the database?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

In Sharepoint Foundation 2013 (and from what I've read, Sharepoint 2013 also), there is currently a bug that, with "check out" features disabled, still allows Adobe Acrobat to flag a file as "checked out". Worse, Adobe has this as the default (the fix I found for this separate problem is here: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2414-disabling-sharepoint-integration-in-adobe-acrobat-and-reader-x-version-10-1 ). I have been through the system top to bottom, and looked around the web, finding others in this conundrum, and there is no current way to fix that, and the only interface control for un-checking-out a file for a user is nonfunctional because it's a file that should not have been able to be checked out.

Up until now, at least as recently as a couple weeks ago, I had been able to edit the database to clear this by nulling out the fields CheckoutUserId, CheckoutDate, and CheckoutExpires in the Sharepoint-generated table WSS_Content_(gibberish).dbo.AllDocs but doing so now has no effect whatsoever.

Is there a new or additional location in the database that needs to be edited to remove these manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prior fix mentioned above (nulling the fields CheckoutUserID, CheckoutDate, and CheckoutExpires in WSS_Content_(gibberish)) allows the files to be cut and pasted from the "Explorer view" and then cut and pasted back in, removing the "checked out" status. It has the downside of changing the edit date, time and user.